# Would it make sense to have an atlatl user in a world where archery is mainstream?

Tags: technology, weapons, fauna, archery

I'm writing a story is set in a Monster Hunter-like world where giant animals roam the landscape. Most of the main characters are archers, but I want to have one who is an atlatl (spear thrower) user for the sake of variety. However, I can't think of many reasons why someone would want to stick to atlatl when bows and arrows are readily available.

Bow and arrow seems to beat atlatls in every aspect, like speed, distance, and accuracy, apart from maybe pure power. Atlatls could be more useful against the larger animals, but the story isn't only about the larger animals, and there will be times when the characters have to hunt smaller animals. Of course, I could just have the character be proficient with both atlatl and bow, but that seems like half-assing it.

Comment: I imagine a bow is much more sensitive to material availability. You can't make a bow with just any wood and fiber. I would think an atlatl is much less sensitive to the material. I mean, bow hunters still exist even though we have guns.

Comment: Just a note: the generic term is a spear-thrower. An atlatl is a specific kind of spear-thrower. For example, in the classical world they used a very different kind of spear-thrower called an [*amentum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amentum) in Latin and an *ankylê* in Greek. (And apparently the Greco-Roman solution increases both the power of the throw *and* the accuracy of the javelin.)

Comment: There are still a few throwing stick users in the real world (or at least were within living memory) where guns are mainstream, so what's your problem? this is really character choice & background / where he was raised and what he was trained to use.

Comment: Atlatl use could be a favorite sport for your character.

Comment: You can set your spear against a charge.

Comment: It seems that this question is a rather open-ended fishing for ideas expedition. Therefore VTC. If you can provide some in-world focus and criteria for good answers, then I'd be happy to rescind my close vote!

Comment: It seems like you're hunting your own doubts on what this specific character would choose to do rather than the world's inconsistencies. Otherwise why "*Atlatls could be more useful against the larger animals*" isn't enough as an answer ? Yes, "*the story isn't only about the larger animals*", but you imply they exist in this "MH"-like world. And since they exist, it's not unseen to have specific tools to deal with them :).

Answer (score 4):

**Yes**

People use sub-optimal tech all the time, especially when you consider a very important factor - the *training* cost. Let us say that your atlatl wielder was raised in an environment without easy access to bows (there can be numerous reasons for this), but easy access to atlatls. Thus, said character would grow up to be a master atlatl user, and once grown up, it would take the character years to learn to use the bow and arrow to be as deadly as he currently is with an atlatl, so the character simply sticks to what they know.

Answer (score 4):

If one is hunting monsters — i.e., creatures that are inclined to attack, as opposed to animals that are more likely to flee — than one shouldn't think strictly in hunting terms. A monster will hunt the hunter, using speed, stealth, or ranged weapons of its own, so an atlatl can have a couple of advantages over a bow:

1. It's a one-handed weapon, meaning the welder can deploy a shield. If a monster is fast, or can fire ranged weapons of its own, a bowman is more exposed.
2. The atlatl handle (the lever used to propel the dart) can double as an impromptu weapon, particularly if the back-end is edged or spiked. That is useful if a monster is closing so quickly that drawing a secondary weapon is problematic. Bows can be used defensively in close combat, sure, but in that context they are effectively unwieldy sticks. An atlatl handle can be designed like a light tomahawk.

It's worth noting that the traditional way of hunting tigers used spears, not archers. Lining up a shot on a quietly grazing deer is a much different experience than dealing with a charging predator.

Answer (score 2):

In a monster hunting world like you say. I can think of one huge advantage.
An atlatl would be more suited and capable of carrying a payload of some sort. Explosive, corrosive, poison, gas, what have you, than an arrow. Not to mention heavier tips or penetrators.

Was not mentioned but pointing out that; many atlatl projectiles were designed to break away or detach from the penetrator on impact, saving the shaft from destruction. Also giving the advantage of carrying more tips/spear heads.

Answer (score 0):

### Specialisation

If the atlatl is likely to be better against some creatures, some hunters will think it worthwhile to learn the skill.  A few will learn it so well that they prefer it to the bow.  I can think of a few reasons why a hunter might prefer the atlatl:

- The hunter (or a friend) once got into a sticky situation with a beast that wasn't stopped by a normal bow but would have been felled by a spear.
- Groups of hunters like to have a spearman with them to deal with the occasional awkward monster.
- The hunter specialises in long, self-sufficient expeditions, and the materials for making a spear and thrower are more widely available than for a bow.
- Family tradition, reinforced by any of the other reasons.

None of these would necessarily stop a person being dual-skilled, but one thing might:

### Injury

Assuming your society doesn't have crossbows:

One of the hunter's hands is injured, paralysed or missing, so (s)he can't draw a bow.  This might be widespread if your society has wars against an enemy that likes to mutilate captured archers (there is an apocryphal story that pre-firearm French soldiers would cut fingers off captured English archers to stop them pulling their bowstrings).

Drawing a bow requires a different set of muscles to throwing.  A back injury that affects the trapezius and/or rhomboid muscles might be more of a problem for an archer than an atlatlist.  Maybe the atlatl-using family above have naturally strong shoulders, long arms and a predisposition to pulled back muscles.

Comment: If your bowstring breaks it is hard to fight with arrows held in the hand, unless you are Legolas.  If you leave your atlatl in your other pants, you still have a big spear.